# Modifying an Attribute's value through method

Tags: python

```
class UniversityAthletics():
    def __init__(self, university_name, sport):
        self.name = university_name
        self.sport = sport
        self.tickets_sold = 10

    def tickets_sold(self):
        """This just tells you how many tickets have been sold"""
        print(str(self.tickets_sold) + " tickets have been sold")

    def describe_athletics(self):
        print(self.name.title() + " " + self.sport.title())

    def in_season(self):
        print(self.sport.title() + " is in season.")

    def set_tickets_sold(self, numticket):
        """This sets the number of tickets that have been sold"""
        self.tickets_sold = numticket

    def increment_tickets_sold(self, moretickets):
        """This increments the number of tickets sold"""
        self.tickets_sold += moretickets

athletics = UniversityAthletics('salisbury university', 'soccer')
athletics.set_tickets_sold(20)
athletics.tickets_sold()
athletics.increment_tickets_sold(500)
athletics.tickets_sold()
```

I tried to make an attribute that sets the number of tickets sold 'set_tickets_sold' and then an attribute that changes the number of the tickets 'increment_tickets_sold' but when I try to set the number of tickets and then call the method 'tickets_sold()' i keep receiving an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:/WorWic/IntroToProgramming/chapter9/University Athletics part
>   2.py", line 29, in 
>       athletics.tickets_sold() TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You are overriding the `ticks_sold()` method with the `tickets_sold` variable.  Change one of their names.  For example, change the variable to `_tickets_sold`

Comment: You used the `tickets_sold` name for two different things on the same object. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `tickets_sold` is both an attribute and a function name. It's getting the attribute and calling that, rather than the function. I suggest renaming your function to something else.

Comment: Thanks i didn't even realize that